# Which version of Cuda toolkit can I use with MSVC 2015

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2015

I recently upgraded from msvc 2005 to 2015.
I have compiled my code with revision 4.2 of cuda toolkit for year. I'm now learning the hard way that there is no forward compatibility betweend visual and cuda, however Google shows that some trick exists to force the compilation (messing up with .props and .targets files).

From what I understand, cuda 4.2 is a no-go. nvcc seems to have an hardcoded check on the msvc revision.
My questions are:

- is there a way to compile with cuda 5.x or 6.x?
- worst case scenario is that I have to update to cuda 7.5, does it even work?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update:  CUDA 8RC supports VS2015 Update 1 officially (not update 2).
For CUDA toolkits prior to CUDA 8RC, none officially list MSVC 2015 as a supported environment, including CUDA 7.5 (the most recent production toolkit, at the moment).

For recent CUDA toolkits, the official support matrix is given in [the windows getting started guide or installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#abstract) which you would have to review for each toolkit version, to find the support for that version.

Since support for a VS version means that the CUDA toolkit will make changes to the VS environment (e.g. installing CUDA build customization rules, what you refer to as "messing with .props and .targets") and also provide appropriate project definition files for each of the cuda sample projects, if you wanted to work around this, you would have to duplicate those functions yourself.  There might be non-standard ways to do this, but you would be operating in unsupported territory.

Comment: I'm not looking for "official" support here, otherwise I would go to nvidia website instead of asking my question here. If I can use any version of the toolkit on msvc 2015 by editing the build rules, kindly let me know how.

Comment: Support for VS goes deeper than updating .props/.targets file (which I can do fine with notepad, thanks @void_ptr). Nvcc checks for environment vars and will refuse to compile if it detects an unsupported revision of msvc

Answer (score 1):

CUDA 8 is the first version to support MSVC 2015, including the community edition (with the exception of cross compiling). At the time of writing this, CUDA 8 is available as a release candidate if you are signed up for the NVIDIA "Accelerated Computing Developer Program".

Comment: For reference, this [presentation from Nvidia](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/webinar/whats-new-cuda-toolkit-8.pdf) (October 2016 GPU Tech Conference) states CUDA 8 support for "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and VS Community 2015".